# View freezes for few seconds while accessing singleton class

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

This is the method I am using

```
 +(dataHandler *)getDataHandler
    {

        dispatch_once(&internalOnceToken,^{
            internalInstance = [[dataHandler alloc] init];
            if(internalInstance) {
                NSLog(@"Internal instance created: %@", internalInstance);
            }
        });
        if(internalOnceToken == -1)
        {
            NSLog(@"Internal instance exists: %@", internalInstance);
        }
        return internalInstance;

    }
```

I tried with dispatch_asyn but its not a static allocation ,In my home screen I have the access for all the data and stored in my singleton class.

But when I try to go from one view controller to home screen its get hang for few seconds how to overcome this?

**Calling Singleton method:**

```
 -(void)responseFunction:(NSMutableDictionary *)response
    {
            BOOL sucess;
            sucess =[[response objectForKey:@"sucess"]boolValue];
            NSLog(@"response Method%@",response);
            NSString *subimages;

            if(!sucess)
            {
                //storing response data to singleton class.
             }
         [self datahandlers];//here i am calling singleton.
    }
```

After storing i am calling singleton class in view did load method

```
if([file.dicCategoryDetails count]!=0&&[file.dicProductDetails count]!=0)
    {
        [self datahandlers];
    }
```

**This is data handler method**

```
-(void)datahandlers
{
    for(NSDictionary *diccategory in file.categoryArr)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dicparsing=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dicparsing setObject:[diccategory objectForKey:@"category"] forKey:@"category"];
        [dicparsing setObject:[diccategory objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
        [dicparsing setObject:[diccategory objectForKey:@"image"] forKey:@"image"];
        [dicparsing setObject:[diccategory objectForKey:@"subcategory"] forKey:@"subcategory"];
        [ArrName addObject:dicparsing];

    }
    NSLog(@"inside data handler%@",ArrName);
    [collectionview reloadData];
    [self scrollView];

}
```

**In view did load**

```
 file= [dataHandler getDataHandler];
```

Comment: what do you mean by "its get struct for few seconds" ? I think that should be UI related issue.

Comment: when i try to access to go home screen its get hang for few second @Mr.T

Comment: its wait upto the data get loads data from singleton class@Mr.T

Comment: show us the code where you are calling your singleton class

Comment: response function method not running all the times ,i have check if singleton class object is nill then the response function getting call. @Mr.T

Comment: Could you post your `[self datahandlers]` method?

Comment: @MattyAyOh wait a minute....

Comment: "`[self datahandlers];//here i am calling singleton.`" **NO**, you are not.  `self.dataHandler` would be equivalent to `[self getDataHandler]`.  I don't see anywhere you call `getDataHandler`

Comment: @stevesliva in view did load i gave that [self gethandler]...

Comment: @KishoreKumar happy to delete if you clarify, but I was taking issue with "After storing i am calling singleton class in view did load method" ... `[self datahandlers]` as well as the previous commented line of code.  The method `-(void) datahandlers` doesn't have any "singleton" code. `getDataHandler` appears to, but it's not at all clear to me what it has to do with the rest.

Comment: @stevesliva inside -(void) datahandlers file.categoryArr is there, this is array i have getting stored data inside singleton method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have done this just using **dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{})**

```
 if([file.dicCategoryDetails count]!=0&&[file.dicProductDetails count]!=0)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                   [self datahandlers];
                });

    }
```

Comment: That little snippet of code for `dispatch_async()` does magic, I've found. If I'm running a progress bar and communicating with a background thread Perl script, and someone clicks cancel, I have to call dispatch_async() or I'll get `BAD_ACCESS` errors. Whenever I see freaky issues in the UI, or `BAD_ACCESS` errors, and when I know I'm doing some timer stuff, I now instinctively react and go for the `dispatch_async` routine to get me out of an issue. I'm so glad you posted this!

Answer (score 0):

If creating internalInstance takes measurable time, then your main thread *will* stall if it needs it, unless you change your code so that internalInstance isn't needed. It could help to call getDataHandler from a background thread as the very first thing when you launch the application, but no call to getDataHandler will return before internalInstance is created.

"call getDataHandler from a background thread":

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [SomeClass getDataHandler];
});
```

inside application:didFinishLaunching: or even earlier.